# ASP.Net MVC: How to handle session start and end by owin middle ware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin-middleware

this is sample code for session start and end.

```
public void Session_OnStart()
{
  Application.Lock();
  Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] + 1;
  Application.UnLock();
}

public void Session_OnEnd()
{
  Application.Lock();
  Application["UsersOnline"] = (int)Application["UsersOnline"] - 1;
  Application.UnLock();
}
```

from MVC6 there will be no global.asax file. so how to handle session start and end by owin middle ware. if possible discuss with code example. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will be very hard to replicate what you want to do in .NET Core 1.0. The `SessionStart` and `SessionEnd` events do not exists (and there is no plan to introduce them) and you can only try to "replicate" them with some tricks.
As clearly pointed out [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-core-1-0) in this extremely clear article,

> Since one of the driving forces behind ASP.NET Core 1.0 is "cloud-readiness", the focus on session management design has been to make it work in a distributed scenario. Session_End only ever fired when sessions used inproc mode (local server memory) and the team have stated that they won't add features that only work locally.

BTW, short answer on session usage:

### Setup

Add the following entries to the dependencies node of your `project.json` file

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Modify you ConfigureServices to activate the Session:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSession(options => { 
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); 
            options.CookieName = ".MyApplication";
        });
}
```

Then you can activate it like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSession();
    //removed for brevity
}
```

### Usage

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Name, "Foo");
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Age", 35);
```

or

```
var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Name");
var age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Age");
```